# preg_match get src of img with specific class

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Let's say i have many images in a string and i only want to get the src of the image with a specific class

```
<img src="image1.jpg"/>
<img src="image2.jpg"/>
<img src="image3.jpg" class="main"/>
```

I wanted to get the src of the third one, which has a class `main`. How do i do that?

```
$pattern = '/< *img[^>]*src *= *["\']?([^"\']*)/i';
preg_match($pattern,$response,$matches);
```

this one matches all img tags.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use a regex to parse HTML. Use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/domdocument) instead.

Here's some code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$imgs = $xp->query("//img[@class='main']");
```

`$imgs` now has a NodeList of images with the `main` class. (I think - I haven't used DOMXPath much)

Comment: How would I be doing that with DOMDocument?