# How to get class and src from html image tag

Tags: php, regex

I want to retrieve the class and `src` of image tag using regex.
The position of `class` and `src` can be anywhere.

I am able to get `src` from `/<img[^>]* src="([^\"]+)"[^>]*>/i`

```
<img width="100" height="100" src="/woocom.png" class="hello hel" alt="woo">

<img width="100" height="100" class="hello hel" src="/woocom.png"  alt="woo">`
```

[Tried Online Regex here](https://regex101.com/r/jknSTx/2)

Comment: i would have thought this is a Javascript problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [preg\_match get src of img with specific class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867650/preg-match-get-src-of-img-with-specific-class)

Comment: You can get it by 2 regex, one after the other. Is there any reason not to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is a PHP tag. I won't recommend using Regular Expressions for this situation. Regular Expression is a hammer and when you understand it, everything around you looks like nail. In PHP we have `DOMDocument` class for this task. Eg below:

```
$d = new DOMDocument();
$d->loadHTML('<img width="100" height="100" src="/woocom.png" class="hello hel" alt="woo">');
$images = $d->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
  echo $image->getAttribute('src');
  echo $image->getAttribute('class');
}
```