# Preg_match_all - 2 first paragraphs after </h2> tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Within a variable `$url`, has the content of a website

inside the div below has all the main content of the page

```
<div id="mw-content-text" lang="pt" dir="ltr" class="mw-content-ltr">
```

I would like to find the `<H2>` that has "**História**"

```
<h2><span id="Hist.C3.B3ria"></span><span class="mw-headline" id="História">História</span><span class="mw-editsection"><span class="mw-editsection-bracket">[</span><a href="/w/index.php?title=Adamantina&amp;veaction=edit&amp;section=1" class="mw-editsection-visualeditor" title="Editar secção: História">editar</a><span class="mw-editsection-divider"> | </span><a href="/w/index.php?title=Adamantina&amp;action=edit&amp;section=1" title="Editar secção: História">editar código-fonte</a><span class="mw-editsection-bracket">]</span></span></h2>
```

between the opening `<h2>` tag of closing `</h2>`  has a lot of code as it is possible to see above

But I need to get only the first two paragraphs `<p>` after the `</h2>` tag that contains "**História**"

```
preg_match_all('/<h2>(.+)</h2>/s', $url, $content);
```

How do I put in the regex that has to have "**História**", and how do I filter only the first two paragraphs after the `</h2>` tag?

Comment: This is called parsing. Don't use Regular Expressions for parsing HTML documents. Use a DOM parser instead.

Comment: Search about: `DOMDocument`

Comment: Thank you very much for the indication I'm reading the PHP manual ([The DOMDocument class](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domdocument.php)). I Found [getelementsbytagname](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php). But how do I convert a variable into `XML`?

Comment: I answered this today: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49081418/6099347

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't even try to do this with Regular Expressions. You are parsing HTML documents and the right tool is a DOM parser. PHP has `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath` classes to work with so don't think twice:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
$domxpath = new DOMXPath($document);
$paragraphs = $domxpath->query('
    //h2[*[
            contains(text(), "História")
          ]
        ]
    /following-sibling::p[
            position() < 3
        ]
');
var_dump($paragraphs);
```

[PHP live demo](https://3v4l.org/WIs7u)

You have two following sibling paragraphs in `$paragraphs`. You need to iterate over them to do whatever you want.

Comment: Also, you can simplify `[*[contains(text(), "História")]]` with `[contains(., "História")]`

Comment: Yes, but I'd prefer to keep it that way. I think will be more readable since I didn't comment code.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. In some paragraphs sometimes appears `[1]` or `[2]`, `[3]` etc of links references, how to remove this from the paragraphs?

Comment: @Gislef When you ask a question on StackOverflow, it is very important that you offer a realistic sample string and your exact expected result in your question.  This allows volunteers to answer your question just once without the risk of follow-up questions.