# PHP regex Pattern Modifiers A and D

Tags: php, regex

Can anyone help me with modifiers `A` and `D`?

I read the description 3 times and did a couple of tests on regex101 but I can not do it so that they would work. Or I can not find an example of what they would have earned.

For example, the regular expression

```
<u>[a-z]+<\/u>
```

works the same way with `A` and without `A`

https://regex101.com/r/X3nkMF/1/

Comment: Regex is wrong tool for it, I have written a similar answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49081418/6099347

Comment: For your case: https://3v4l.org/nSBq6

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Yes, I know, thanks, it's just an example for training

Answer (score 1):

**[See PHP/PCRE Manual: Possible modifiers in regex patterns](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)**

---

**`A`**`(PCRE_ANCHORED)`

> If this modifier is set, the pattern is forced to be "**anchored**", that is, it is constrained **to match only at the start of the string** which is being searched (the "subject string"). This effect can also be achieved by appropriate constructs in the pattern itself, which is the only way to do it in Perl.

*Example*: `/bar/A` [matches `bar baz`](https://regex101.com/r/IvsCzZ/1) but [not `foo bar`](https://regex101.com/r/IvsCzZ/2)

There is also the `\A` [anchor](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html#az) available to match start of the string. This is helpful in multiline mode (using the `m` [flag](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)) where `^` matches start of each line.

---

**`D`**`(PCRE_DOLLAR_ENDONLY)`

> If this modifier is set, a dollar metacharacter in the pattern matches only at the end of the subject string. **Without this modifier, a dollar also matches immediately before the final character** if it is a newline (but not before any other newlines). This modifier is ignored if m modifier is set. There is no equivalent to this modifier in Perl.

*Example*: `/foo$/D` [matches `foo`](https://regex101.com/r/K0XkxH/1) but [not `foo\n`](https://regex101.com/r/K0XkxH/2)

There is also the lower `\z` anchor available to match the absolute end of the string: `foo\z` Whereas the upper `\Z` would behave similar the dollar sign and also match before last `\n` with the difference that in multiline mode (`m` flag) upper `\Z` won't match at the end of each line.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <u>[a-z]+<\/u>
> ```

It does not matter whether you anchor that pattern to the beginning or not, it will always match the first line of

> ```
> <u>word</u>
> <u>main</u>
> ```

only - unless you add the `g` modifier to not stop after the first match.

So add `/g` and `/gA`, and then you will see what a difference this `A` makes ...

Comment: Yes, I see, thank you. But if I remove g, there is no difference. In addition, there is no `g` modifier in the PHP language, only `preg_match` and `preg_match_all`

Comment: _"But if I remove g, there is no difference"_ - of course there isn't, because without it only looks for the first match. That first match is at the very beginning of the input text already - so it simply doesn't matter whether you request via `A` that it is or not, that is just superfluous. If you want to see the effect of `A` without `g`, then you must create an example that does _not_ have the pattern match at the very beginning of the test input, for example by placing a simple space before it - https://regex101.com/r/X3nkMF/2/ now try toggling `/A` off ...

Comment: _"In addition, there is no g modifier in the PHP language, only preg_match and preg_match_all"_ - well then just use the appropriate one, for whichever case you need.